# Is there a way to generate JSDoc comments in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I am currently developing a NodeJS project and found out that there is no built in functionality to create JSDoc comments for functions/methods.

I am aware of the TypeScript definitions that exist but I couldn't really find anything to match what I need.

WebStorm, for example, has some pretty neat JSDoc functionalities. Can one somehow achieve a similar functionality?

Answer (score 307, accepted):

Visual Studio Code 1.10 is now able to generate JSDoc comments.

Just type `/**` above the function

[image: screenshot of Visual Studio Code UI assisting with the generation of a JSDoc comment]

**See Also**:

- [VS Code Docs > Languages > Javascript > JSDoc Support](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_jsdoc-support)
- [VS Code February 2017 Release Notes > Auto JSDoc Comments](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_auto-jsdoc-comments)

Comment: Nice feature! Yet it doesn't seem to work with fat-arrow functions, and it doesn't add @returns and {type} for some reason--at least on my setup. Just a heads up that people might consider using a 3-party plugin :).

Comment: For @returns you can keep an eye on this ticket: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14248

Comment: My  visual studio code version is 1.24.1 . Still @returns is not added.

Comment: Is there a way to automatically add them when writing a function?

Comment: The feature is actually triggered by typing `/** */`. This automatically happens if you have auto-closing of brackets enabled.

Comment: Is there a way to assign this to a keyboard shortcut? I know `/**` isn't _that_ long but it'd be nice with how many JSDoc comments I'm making nowadays.

Comment: This is a nice feature and one that is compatible many other documentation libraries like [Compodoc](https://compodoc.app/) for generating automated documentation. As @iMe mentioned, for `@param` and `@return` tags you can use this useful library [Add jsdoc comments](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stevencl.addDocComments)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg In fact, I couldn't trigger this snippet with auto-closing brackets disabled. Guess I have to get used to those now...

Answer (score 38):

I really like "Document This".

#### Installation

Launch VS Code Quick Open (⌘+P), paste the following command, and press enter.
`ext install docthis`

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oouo-diogo-perdigao.docthis

It has some nice features like adding doc blocks to an entire file.

Comment: The link is dead, now use [this](https://github.com/oouo-diogo-perdigao/vscode-docthis) fork from GitHub https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=oouo-diogo-perdigao.docthis

Comment: October 2022: The extension is called *Document This* and was written by *oouo-diogo-perdigao* .  The link in this answer works. I had a fresh new laptop with the latest VS Code.  This is the only extension that got JavaDoc block comments working!

Answer (score 18):

Maybe give this JSDoc extension a try: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/stevencl.addDocComments

You can install extensions in VS Code from `View` > `Command Palette`

[image: Install Extensions]

Comment: it was removed. Didn't find neither in the extensions marketplace nor the link

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who, like me, is to lazy to type /** every time they want to insert some JSDoc comments I found the following solution to be quite effective. *Note this is implemented with code-server 3.12.0*

1. Install the macros extension https://github.com/geddski/macros
2. Add the following block to your `settings.json`

```
"macros": {
  "JSDoc": [
    {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "/**"}},
    "insertSnippet"
  ]
}
```

3. Add the following to your `keybindings.json`

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+/",
  "command": "macros.JSDoc",
  "when": "editorFocus"
}
```

---

Now whenever you type `ctrl+shift+/` intellisense autocomplete will pop-up, hit enter and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

A related one.

I was finding for Visual Studio 2017 Community edition, below helped:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MichaelObermeyer.DocStubsJs2017

Answer (score 2):

The best result for me (in 2023) was with `JSDoc Generator`:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=crystal-spider.jsdoc-generator

It was the only one that I found that works fine, as VS Code integrated `JSDoc comment` didn't add the types, `oouo-diogo-perdigao.docthis` didn't add the types properly in `@return`, several old extensions were dead, etc.

Answer (score 0):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kimlimjustin.jsdoc-generator

just select the whole function till the first block `{` and command vscode to generate jsdoc. works with arrow functions/typescript.

Answer (score -3):

Document this has worked perfectly for me