# Can I configure how VSCode autocompletes JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc, object-destructuring

VSCode lets me [autocomplete a JSDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42805312/1075247) when I start typing `/**` which is nice, and it even fills in some params.

But a) it defaults all the params to `*` and b) it doesn't help when I'm destructuring an object in a function definition.

e.g. if I had

```js
const FloopThePig = ({pigCount, floopStrength}) => { ...
```

Then autocompleting the JSDoc gives me:

```js
/**
 * @param {*} param0 
 */
const FloopThePig = ({pigCount, floopStrength}) => { ...
```

When really I'd like to customise it to something like

```js
/**
 * @param {object} props
 * @param {unknown} props.pigCount 
 * @param {unknown} props.floopStrength
 */
const FloopThePig = ({pigCount, floopStrength}) =>
```

I'm not set on it having to be 'unknown' but something other than `*`, and documenting the destructured params is what I've been trying to find.

Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: It is a requested feature that has not yet been implemented. [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27942).